# How to popup a bootstrap modal on browser tab change?

Tags: angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, angular9

I have made an app where if a user changes the tab for more than 1 time the app will navigate to another component. Up to this it's perfect but I want the app should also show a warning if he changes tab for the 1st time.
For now I have set a simple `alert` message to appear but I want a bootstrap modal to appear.

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

c = 0;

@HostListener('window:blur', ['$event'])
  onBlur(event: FocusEvent): void {
    this.c++;
    if(this.c == 1)
    {alert('You shouldn't switch to another tab');}
    if(this.c > 1)
    {this.route.navigate(['./thankyou']);}
  }
```

This is my code.
How can I modify it ?